# How to move the middle div down if the left and right div come too close to each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, margin

I have 3 div elements.
[left]    [center]    [right]

if [left] and [right] keep coming close to each other, as they are about to touch the center div, the center div should move down as it is shown in the below diagram.

[left] _______ [right]

```
   [center]
```

I have tried this enough but not able to achieve this position. I am sure this is not a new concept. I tried flex-box but not able to achieve the desired behavior. I will appreciate any kind of help. Thank you.

Comment: can you share your markup

Comment: when does left and right div comes close

Comment: Can you show the HTML? We want to avoid situations where people think up a solution, and you will reply that it isn't applicable to your specific problem because your setup is different.

Comment: Hello guys, sorry I cannot paste the code due to IP.

Comment: What i meant while shrinking the left and right div is that when the browser is squeezed to such n extent that the left and right div start to overlap the center div, the center div goes down. How to make the center div go down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate my point about lack of information in the question, here is a solution that does exactly what you ask for, but won't help solve your problem. Please provide more context.

```css
div {line-height:3em; text-align:center}
.left, .right {width:200px; max-width:calc(50% - 2px); float:left; border:1px solid; overflow:hidden}
.right {float:right}
```

```html
<div class="left">This is the left div</div>
<div class="right">This is the right div</div>
<div class="middle">This is the center div</div>
```

Comment: This is probably *not-an-answer*, ... but I upvoted  it anyway :-)

Comment: @vals Sure it's not an answer, but do you have any idea how hard it is to put a stacksnippet in a comment?

Comment: I didn't explain myself well. I fully agree with your idea of posting this answer.

Comment: Mr Lister: perfect answer, thanks for the help :-) Appreciate it.

Comment: Mr Lister: perfect answer, thanks for the help. Appreciate it.